# Edit summary options

Tags: script, editing

## Description

Gives you little checkboxes above the edit summary with preset options like "formatted code" or "removed signature."

## Screenshots

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

## Userscript

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/184914

## Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Edit summary options
// @description  Gives you little checkboxes above the edit summary with preset options like "formatted code" or "removed signature."
// @version    1.0
// @match      http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match      http://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match      http://*.onstartups.com/*
// @match      http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match      http://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match      http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match      http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match      http://*.superuser.com/*
// @copyright  Public Domain (no copyright)
// ==/UserScript==

var config = localStorage.__edit_summary_opts_config || {
  Grammar: 'fixed grammar',
  Spelling: 'fixed spelling',
  Format: 'formatting',
  'Code Format': 'formatted code',
  Dethank: 'removed thanks',
  Desig: 'removed signature',
  Degreet: 'removed greeting'
}

$('.edit-post').click(function() {
  var intr = setInterval(function() {
    var ec = $('.edit-comment')
    if (ec.length) {
      clearInterval(intr)
      ec.css('opacity', '1')
      var i = 0
      var summaryDiv = ec.parents().eq(4)
      for (var x in config) {
        summaryDiv.before($('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb' + i})
                                      .change((function(x) { return function() {
                                        if (this.checked) {
                                          ec.val(ec.val() ? ec.val() + ', ' + config[x] : config[x])
                                        } else {
                                          ec.val(ec.val().replace(new RegExp(config[x] + '(, )?|, ' + config[x] + '$'), ''))
                                        }
                                      }})(x)))
                  .before($('<label>').attr({for: 'cb' + i++})
                                      .css({padding: '5px'})
                                      .text(x))
      }
      summaryDiv.after($('<button>').text('Edit')
                                    .click(function() {
                                      config = localStorage.__edit_summary_opts_config = JSON.parse(prompt('Enter JSON, formatted like {"checkbox name": "value", ...}', JSON.stringify(config)) || JSON.stringify(config))
                                    }))
    }
  }, 100)
})
```

## Issues

- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Make `config`... well... configurable, so user can set his/her own options (save with `localStorage`)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Make it work for suggested edits too
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Text in the edit summary is a bit messed up when you click edit a second time on a different post on the same page

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I don't see the check boxes when I click the *edit* link and launch the Edit page.

Comment: @ADTC You don't have 2000 rep. This script requires that.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I'm always making suggested edits, and I would find this script incredibly useful in making it easier. I'm constantly finding myself typing the same summaries over and over again.

Comment: @ADTC Alright, added [feature-request] (I haven't actually worked on this for a while... or at all, so I think I will now :P)

Comment: Mind explaining what `.edit-post` is, and whether it has to be `click`ed before the check boxes can be displayed? I had been trying to modify the script to work with the *suggested edit* page, but can't get it to even make an alert for the life of me.. I thought both *suggested edit* and *>2000 rep edit* are the same page **in code**, so it just flies past my head why this script wouldn't work for *suggested edit*...

Comment: Actually Chrome's Inspector shows `$ is not defined`. Even changing to `jQuery` doesn't help: `jQuery is not defined`. Now the question is, how did you get the extension to run its JS only *after* jQuery JS was loaded?

Comment: I have made changes to the script to make it run in Chrome, and to make it work for suggested edits. **Note that this is *not* a revised version.** Doorknob, please use this script to improve yours. I hope you will test in Chrome as I found the localStorage to break. [Download from Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41098084/184914-debug.user.js)

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all - I have 2000 rep, but I don't see the checkboxes

Comment: For those having problems with this script, see [Request for script, or fix, to add Edit-Reason checkboxes](http://stackapps.com/questions/5023/request-for-script-or-fix-to-add-edit-reason-checkboxes) -- where you can find whole new script(s) that are tested against the latest Stack Exchange and work for all edits, suggested edits, and review edits -- irregardless of how much rep you have.