# Request for script, or fix, to add Edit-Reason checkboxes

Tags: support, editing, script-request

I've found a Stack Exchange userscript which looks GREAT - it would make things so much easier for me:

[The Edit summary options script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4420/edit-summary-options)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all! I'm not sure why.

My question is possibly a bit off topic, but I'm not quite sure where else I could ask. What's wrong with the code in that script? Can anybody fix it? And if not, can anybody make a new stackapp with that same concept?
It would make my life, and probably many other lives, much easier (at least on Stack Overflow)!

Comment: @BrockAdams I happen to have 2k rep on StackOverflow! I did try the "improved" version in the comments with no luck...

Comment: Why don't you leave a comment on that post? That person is pretty active on various Stack Exchange sites IIRC.

Comment: @Antony That's a good idea. I hadn't commented because I thought it'd be useless - others have already mentioned the issue to the OP and the OP hasn't fixed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, went ahead and banged out a script for this; Happy Christmas!

**To install**, click [here (*SE Edit Reasoner* install at Github)](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-Edit-Reasoner/raw/master/stack_exchange_edit_reasoner.user.js).

**To preview the source**, click [here (*SE Edit Reasoner*  preview at Github)](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-Edit-Reasoner/blob/master/stack_exchange_edit_reasoner.user.js).

---

This userscript requires an engine that supports both `@require` and the various `@grant`ed APIs.
It was *tested* on **Firefox + Greasemonkey** and **Chrome + Tampermonkey**.

---

To-Do's, Issues, etc. (Pending time and interest):

1. Make a proper post with screenshots and more information (tab order, GitHub cross links, etc.).
2. Done! <s>Add the options dialog to allow easy customization of the Reasons list.</s>
3. Possible feature: Add site by site customization of edit reasons.
4. Possible feature: Add a full-auto Reason filler to facilitate mass retagging, etc.
5. Possible feature: Add hotkeys for first 9 reasons.
6. See script source for more possible roadmap notes.
7. No known bugs on Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I'll award the bounty in a couple of hours when the system allows me. As a sidenote, this worked when I put it in with Tampermonkey, but without Tampermonkey, it didn't work.

Comment: Brock, I'm very impressed with this. Way to go! Very clean, easy to use...just perfect all around. It'll be even better with the Settings functionality, but I can just edit the reasons directly in the code if I want to. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I didn't get to it before you burned a bounty (Bounties don't normally work here on StackApps).  It was on my "Rainy Day fun" list and I'll be using the script myself if I ever do much reviewing again.

Comment: Updated the script on GitHub with the configuration dialog.

Comment: Awesome. I love the update. Very cool. You should make a thread for this on it's own